# Problema con el envio Parametros Nusoap PHP a SAP

Tags: php, webservice, sap

Tengo un problema al momento de realizar una integracion de PHP (nusoap) con SAP, la conexion responde 200 OK pero devuelve un valor NULL, creo yo que el fallo esta en como paso los parametros, este es el codigo:

```
    $client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
    $client->setCredentials($usuario,$pass);
    $client->setEndpoint($endpoint); 
    $client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
    $client->http_encoding='gzip,deflate';
    $client->namespaces = array(
 'soapenv' => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
 'tg' => "http://www.rutadeltg.com/xml/tgweb",
 'asi' => "http://rutadelasi/asi/");
  $person = array('CedulaCliente' =>    $cedula,'CanalDistribucion'=>$canal,'TipoPedido'=>$tipopedido);
  $result = $client->call('SI_Get_Order', $person, 'urn:VentaDirecta:modelo:sap','http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1');
```

Comment: cuando envia status 200 es que el servicio se ejecuto perfectamente y puede no devolver nada lee https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP

Comment: El web service de SAP haciendo la peticion correctamente devuelve un valor String, hay alguna idea del porque el web service SAP no recibe los parámetros?

Answer (score 0):

Este funciona para mi .. .aunque es un webservice que me envia XML, si el tuyo no envia xml .. entonces no uses la linea: $test = simplexml_load_string($data->SI_Get_OrderResult->any);

y al final pruebalo con "echo print_r($data);" en vez de "echo print_r($test);"

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 900);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15);

$params = array('CedulaCliente'=>$cedula, 'CanalDistribucion'=>$canal, 'TipoPedido'=>$tipopedido); 

$wsdl = 'http://URL.asmx?wsdl';

$options = array(
  'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
  'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
  'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
  'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
  'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
  'connection_timeout'=>15,
  'trace'=>true,
  'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
  'exceptions'=>true,
);
try {
 $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
 $data = $soap->SI_Get_Order($params);
 $test = simplexml_load_string($data->SI_Get_OrderResult->any);
}
 catch(Exception $e) {
 die($e->getMessage());
}

echo print_r($test);
```